# Operator overloading performance

Tags: c++

I was reading a paper on automatic differentiation and the authors mention: "Likewise, using operator overloading may introduce method dispatches with attendant costs, which, compared to raw numerical computation of the original function, can easily amount to a slow down of an order of magnitude."

Basically, can you explain the first part of this quote regarding operator overloading and whether it applies to C++? I don't really have an understanding of the language's internals.

The surrounding text doesn't add any further explanation.

Comment: @Buddy What is the connection between the linked question and this one?

Comment: @Buddy: As far as I can see, it doesn't look like that link discusses the overhead of call vs inline.

Comment: From the part you cite, I can only assume that the paper's author had no idea of what he was talking about. An overloaded operator is pretty much a function with a different syntax, and like every function can be defined inline.

Comment: This question pertains to specific compilers . A bad compiler might do what the author says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be a large difference between:

```
Complex a(1.0, 2.0), b(1.1, 2.2);
Complex c;

c = a + b;
```

and:

```
Complex a(1.0, 2.0), b(1.1, 2.2);
Complex c;

c.re = a.re + b.re;
c.im = a.im + b.im;
```

if the `Complex operator+(Complex lhs, Complex rhs);` function is not possible to inline. However, if the compile can inline the code, there would be no difference at all.

So it's very much dependent on the relative overhead of the call to the operator and the complexity of the actual call. Doing `std::string operator+(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs);` with a pair of strings that is several kilobytes will have very little overhead in the call to the `operator+` , compared to the adding of `double` or `float` numbers in the complex math case above. For short strings, the overhead is much larger, in relative terms.

Here is an example:

oper.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Complex.h"
#include "Complex2.h"

const int SIZE = 80000;

template<typename CPLX> 
void Fill(CPLX* arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = CPLX(rand(), rand());
    }
}

template<typename CPLX> 
void DummyFunc(CPLX* arr)
{
    double sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum = arr[i].re + arr[i].im;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum:" << sum << std::endl;
}

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}

void RunFunc1()
{
    Complex arr1[SIZE];
    Complex arr2[SIZE];
    Complex arr3[SIZE];

    Fill(arr1);
    Fill(arr2);

    unsigned long long t = rdtsc();
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr3[i] = arr2[i] + arr1[i];
    }
    t = rdtsc() - t;
    std::cout << "Time=" << t << std::endl;
    DummyFunc(arr3);
}

void RunFunc2()
{
    Complex2 arr1[SIZE];
    Complex2 arr2[SIZE];
    Complex2 arr3[SIZE];

    Fill(arr1);
    Fill(arr2);

    unsigned long long t = rdtsc();
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr3[i] = arr2[i] + arr1[i];
    }
    t = rdtsc() - t;
    std::cout << "Time=" << t << std::endl;
    DummyFunc(arr3);
}

void RunFunc3()
{
    Complex2 arr1[SIZE];
    Complex2 arr2[SIZE];
    Complex2 arr3[SIZE];

    Fill(arr1);
    Fill(arr2);

    unsigned long long t = rdtsc();
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        arr3[i].im = arr2[i].im + arr1[i].im;
        arr3[i].re = arr2[i].re + arr1[i].re;
    }
    t = rdtsc() - t;
    std::cout << "Time=" << t << std::endl;
    DummyFunc(arr3);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    RunFunc1();
    RunFunc2();
    RunFunc3();
}
```

Complex.h:

```
class Complex
{
public:
    Complex(double r, double i) : re(r), im(i) {}
    Complex() {};
    double re;
    double im;
};

Complex operator+(Complex lhs, Complex rhs);
```

Complex2.h:

```
class Complex2
{
public:
    Complex2(double r, double i) : re(r), im(i) {}
    Complex2() {};
    double re;
    double im;
};


Complex2 operator+(Complex2 lhs, Complex2 rhs) 
{
    return Complex2(lhs.re + rhs.re, lhs.im + rhs.im);
}
```

Complex.cpp:

```
#include "Complex.h"

Complex operator+(Complex lhs, Complex rhs) 
{
    return Complex(lhs.re + rhs.re, lhs.im + rhs.im);
}
```

Build with:

```
clang++ -O2 -c Complex.cpp
clang++ -O2 oper.cpp Complex.o -std=c++11
```

Results look something like this:

```
Time=3265033
Sum:7.09575e+09
Time=1728941
Sum:6.72663e+09
Time=1705123
Sum:2.92692e+09
```

As you can see, the first time is about 2x that of the two other solutions. This is because the compiler can not inline the `Complex.cpp` code when it is in a separate translation unit (compiled separately)

Comment: Makes sense. Can you explain why a compiler wouldn't be able to inline the overloaded operator function?

Comment: The TYPICAL cases for "not inlining" is either that the source is in a different source file (different translation unit), or that the function is called many times and large enough that the compiler doesn't think it's "makes it better" to inline the function.